# How to set global properties for ag-Grid?

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

Let's say I need to set `height` for my `ag-grid`. I have to set it on the columns configuration, like that (in an Angular controller):

```
this.myAgGridOptions = {
  columnDefs: ...,
  rowData: ...,
  headerHeight: 42,
  rowHeight: 42
}
```

Now, if I have 10 different agGrid in my whole application, is there a way to set these properties only once for all of them, and not for each agGrid declaration?

My question is for the Angular 1 version of AgGrid, but if the solution can be used for any version of AgGrid, it will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What will probably work best is to use the [extend method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) that angular provides

So you could have something like this:

```
this.GlobalAgGridOptions = {
  headerHeight: 42,
  rowHeight: 42
}

this.myAgGridOptionsOne = {
    rowData: rowDataOne,
    columnDefs: columnDefsOne
}

this.myAgGridOptionsTwo = {
    rowData: rowDataTwo,
    columnDefs: columnDefsTwo
}

angular.extends(this.mygridOptionsOne, this.GlobalOptions);
angular.extends(this.mygridOptionsTwo, this.GlobalOptions);
```

Now both the grid options should have the global options. I guess I am supposing that you are going to be creating somewhat different gridOptions for each grid that you plan on creating. I hope I am supposing correctly

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. I solved my problem by doing something similar, by creating an Angular constant that contains the global agGrid options.